# Allow calling shell functions with globs without making the user quote

Tags: bash, shell

Consider the following convenience bash function that is intended not to descend into directories but instead just list them:

```
12:17:03/shared $type lld
lld is a function
lld ()
{
    ls -drlta $1
}
```

Let us try to use it:

```
12:17:44/shared $lld pic*
-rw-r--r--@ 1 steve  staff  249245 Jan 27 16:43 PIClustering.png
```

That is not correct: but if we add double quotes then it gives correct results:

```
12:17:20/shared $lld "pic*"
-rw-r--r--@ 1 steve  staff  249245 Jan 27 16:43 PIClustering.png
-rw-r--r--   1 steve  staff       2004 Jan 27 18:07 pic-15.txt
drwxr-xr-x  42 steve  staff       1428 Jan 30 14:30 pic
drwxr-xr-x  43 steve  staff       1462 Feb 18 14:33 picsubmean
drwxr-xr-x  41 steve  staff       1394 Mar 21 08:32 picschur
```

The question is: how to modify the lld() function to achieve the latter behavior without requiring quotes?

Comment: You can't. Your function isn't the problem. The shell has *already* expanded the glob before your `lld` function even sees the arguments. Well you can but only by turning off shell globbing entirely.

Comment: Add `printf 'argv: %s\n' "$@"` to your `lld` function to see that it gets glob expanded arguments.

Comment: i think ur correct. feel free to add answer. in the meantime I am going to add one provisionally.

Comment: @etan  Actually @ cyrus came up with a precise solution.

Comment: No they didn't. See my comment. That answer just uses all the expanded arguments to the function. That helps for this specific case. It doesn't for *many* other cases (cases where the un-expanded glob needs to be used literally by the internal command).

Comment: @etan It answered this specific question.  I am not disputing your comment about the shell glob expansion: but the answer given by cyrus does meet the requirements here.

Comment: It works for this specific instance. The question was about avoiding the expansion not making that function work even even with expansion but <shrug>.

Comment: Why not a simple `alias`? e.g. `alias lld='ls -drlta'`

Comment: @EtanReisner  I can see now re-reading the title your position on the solution.

Comment: @EtanReisner Obviously you are technically correct: the best kind of correct. I took the liberty of rephrasing the question to not assume a solution, so now the question should fit both the actual problem and the best solution.

Comment: @thatotherguy As rewritten the new title question is impossible. You cannot prevent expansion from occurring *before* you get control of the environment. You can use the expanded arguments if they are what you need but if you needed the unexpanded form you have already lost the game.

Comment: @EtanReisner You're reading it as "calling shell functions with literal globs that are then expanded in the function", which I wouldn't consider to be necessarily implied by this title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
ls -drlta $1
```

by

```
ls -drlta "$@"
```

---

Globs are expanded before functions or commands are called, and each result becomes a separate argument. `lld pic*` is shorthand for (and indistinguishable from):

```
lld "PIClustering.png" "pic" "pic-15.txt" "picsubmean" "picschur"
```

Knowing this, the solution is obvious: instead of listing just the first file specified (`$1`), you should list all files specified (`"$@"`).

Comment: that works!  now glad to have asked : had a hunch there were some construct that I were unaware of in bash that would come into play here.

Comment: This doesn't "work". The glob has *already* been expanded. This will function as long as you don't care about that time-of-expansion distinction. Try this with `grep` instead of `ls` and it will fail if the pattern matches existing filenames, etc.

Comment: I should be clear, this is exactly correct in terms of how to make the function correctly use all the arguments it has been provided. This just doesn't solve the titular question that was asked. It does, however, solve the specific problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

From @etan's comments it is not possible to achieve precisely what I was looking for. The following is a reasonable facsimile:

12:33:10/shared $type lld
lld is a function
lld ()
{
    ls -drlta $1*
}

Then use it by:

```
12:17:44/shared $lld pic
-rw-r-----@  1 steve  staff     184655 Jan 26 00:16 picInputOutputs.png
-rw-r--r--   1 steve  staff  794810294 Jan 26 01:11 pic.0126.tgz
drwxr-xr-x  43 steve  staff       1462 Jan 27 16:23 picpy
-rw-r--r--@  1 steve  staff     249245 Jan 27 16:43 PIClusteringFiveCirclesInputsAndOutputs.png
-rw-r--r--   1 steve  staff       2004 Jan 27 18:07 pic-15.txt
drwxr-xr-x  48 steve  staff       1632 Jan 30 12:35 pic.old
```

Notice: *without* the glob/asterisk.  This function tacks it on automatically. I wanted this helper because it gets used many times daily.

Comment: You also know that a simple `alias` in your (or the system) `bashrc` (or similar) will work as well. Simply use: `alias lld='ls -drlta'` and you will not have to worry about the expansion issue... Try it with another alias, say `lldd` and compare `:p`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  Well ur correct. I had been using alias for something similar in the past and the way was using it had issues. In the particular formulation above the alias works fine.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In any case it was also useful to see the use of the expanded args "$@" by cyrus and also the confirmation of shell glob expansion by etan.

Comment: Yes, but pay attention to Etan's comments, he doesn't make them lightly, and they are rarely wrong.

Comment: umm i mentioned that I already have done so. oh. i see he added another one to the accepted answer.